# The server principal "xxx" is not able to access the database "dbbb" under the current security context

Tags: sql-server

I have this DB procedure:

```
USE dbbbb

DECLARE @returncode int  
EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "SSIS_some.dtsx"'  

select  @returncode
```

I launch the script using the command prompt:

```
sqlcmd -S server\instance -i C:script.sql -o C:\Logs.txt
```

But when I run this stored proc, I get:

```
The server principal "xxx" is not able to access the database "dbbb" under the current security context
```

Comment: Wait, just to confirm, you have a SQL script, that called `xp_cmdshell`, which is therefore command line, to then call `dtexec`, and you call that from command line...? Don't you think that's overly complicating the problem a little...? Command Line -> SQL Server -> Command Line -> DTExec. Just call `dtexec` straight from the command line... Cut out all the middle men.

Comment: the command "sqlcmd -S server \ instance -i C: script.sql -o C: \ Logs.txt" I put it in a .bat file that I will then have to schedule in the Windows tasks

Comment: So why not just put `dtexec /f "SSIS_some.dtsx"` into the Windows Task Scheduler? Or, better yet, just schedule the SSIS package in SQL Server Agent directly, without calling dtexec.

Comment: For the sake of brevity I have entered only the first line for dtexec, but I have 5 lines with different dtsx files

Comment: So that's 5 steps, in a single Job...

Answer (score 1):

It will probably help your understanding here if I first explain that logins and users are different in SQL Server.

The login is the thing that connects to the server in the first place. It has a username and a password, or uses windows authentication. Logins exist at the server level. That is why a login is called a "server principal".

A user is something that exists inside a particular database. Users are associated with logins. A users is also known as a "database principal".

Since you don't specify a database for sqlcmd to connect to, the login will connect to a default database, which is probably the `master` database (probably using `guest`. We don't need to go into the details of that just now). It now has a "security context" in that database. You can think of this as meaning the login has connected to the server, and has now "become" some user in a database.

You then try to change to the `dbbbb` database. But if no user has been created in the `dbbbb` database for the login, you can't switch to that database. Instead, you get the error `The server principal "xxx" is not able to access the database "dbbb" under the current security context`.

The solution is to create a user in database `dbbb` for the login `xxx` and grant that user the necessary permissions to do whatever it needs to do.

Indeed, for what you are doing you don't even need to switch databases. The `use dbbb` statement isn't doing anything useful. But I thought I'd provide the complete explanation anyway.

Now, having said all that, Larnu's comments are exactly right and the design is quite convoluted. There's no need to use task scheduler, sqlcmd, and xp_cmdshell. SQL Agent is a scheduler built right into sql server that knows how to run ssis packages. You just create an agent job, add a step, and choose "SSIS package" as the step type.